# Scrollbar on tkinter canvas/frame not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-scrolledtext

I adapted the solution by Bryan Oakley at [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter) to implement a scrollbar on a tkinter Frame. (The code reads key/value pairs from a dict and generates a series of editable entries in table format, prefaced by a checkbox that enables the user to delete entries.) I can get his code working but not my own: the scrollbar is present but does not become enabled. The background colors suggest that the canvas is expanding just as the frame is, which would explain why no working scrollbar, but I don't know why the canvas expands. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
def make_table(map, widget, prefix):
    
    
    delete_label_str = StringVar()
    delete_label_str.set('Delete')
    delete_label = tk.Label(widget, textvariable=delete_label_str, width=6, height=1, justify=tk.CENTER)
    delete_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    abbrev_label_str = StringVar()
    abbrev_label_str.set('Name')
    abbrev_label = tk.Label(widget, textvariable=abbrev_label_str, height=1, width=6, justify=tk.CENTER)
    abbrev_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    def_label_str = StringVar()
    def_label_str.set('Definition')
    def_label = tk.Label(widget, textvariable=def_label_str, height=1, width=45, justify=tk.LEFT)
    def_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
    
    
    if not map or len(map) == 0:
        return
    row_num = 1
    for key in map.keys():
        delete_var_name = prefix + str(row_num)
        globals()[delete_var_name] = BooleanVar()
        globals()[delete_var_name].set(False)
        delete_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(widget, variable=globals()[delete_var_name], height=1, anchor=tk.W)
        delete_checkbox.grid(row=row_num, column=0)
        e1 = tk.Entry(widget, width=6, )
        e1.grid(row=row_num, column=1)
        e1.insert(END, key)

        e2 = tk.Entry(widget, width=45, )
        e2.grid(row=row_num, column=2)
        e2.insert(END, map[key])
        row_num+=1
    

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    #Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
    

def show_abbrevs():
    dlog = tk.Toplevel(root)
    dlog.title('Abbreviations')
    dlog.geometry('425x325')
    delete_prefix = 'delete_abbr_value'
    global cur_path
    if cur_path:
        basepath = os.path.splitext(cur_path)[0]
        fname = basepath + '.abb'
    else:  
        fname = my_path + '/picardy.abb'
    canvas = tk.Canvas(dlog, borderwidth=0, background="blue")
    table_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, pady=10, padx=5, background="yellow")
    vsb = tk.Scrollbar(dlog, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview, )
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

    vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    canvas.create_window((4,4), window=table_frame, anchor="nw")

    table_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas:onFrameConfigure(canvas))
      
    table_frame.pack()
    #table_frame.focus_set()
    
    make_table(abbrev_map, table_frame, delete_prefix)
    button_frame = tk.Frame(dlog, pady=10)
    
    new = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Add", width=10, height=1, command=lambda:add_entry(table_frame, delete_prefix))
    new.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
    delete = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Delete", width=10, height=1, command=lambda:delete_entries(table_frame, delete_prefix))
    delete.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
    save = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Save", width=10, height=1, command=lambda:save_entries(table_frame, fname, delete_prefix))
    save.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
    button_frame.pack()
```

Comment: Remove `table_frame.pack()`.

Comment: Brilliant! What's the reason?

Comment: It is because you have already used the correct way to put the frame into the canvas: `canvas.create_window(...)`.  Putting the frame into the canvas using `.pack()` will adjust the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code in simple example and worked when used `scrollregion` arugment in canvas

```
# 1200 is the max height, scroll can reach
scrollregion=(0,0,0,1200)

# example

import tkinter as tk
root= tk.Tk()
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 75*3, height = (50*20)+50, scrollregion=(0,0,0,1200))

table_frame = tk.Frame(canvas1, pady=10, padx=5, background="yellow")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas1.yview, )
canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas1.create_window((4,4), window=table_frame, anchor="nw")
```

i was creating small dynamic helper functions to create grid with unlimited rows and max 3 cols you can test the scroll in this example full code and grid Drawer function

https://github.com/MahmoudHegazi/tkinter_grid_lib